# Android - zoom-in in Hybrid setting, Google map shows nothing but empty background

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, hybrid

In my app I am showing a Google map with pointer. I have submitted the app in `market` and I checked it by downloading from the market.

The map in default is shown in Hybrid view. Normally the map looks good but when I try to zoom in the map shows an empty background as in the following figure
[image]

Following is my map code:

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        Point screenPts = new Point();

        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-100, null);         
        return true;
    }
} 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    Map = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.MapBtn);
    Hybrid = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.hybridBtn);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController(); 

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 

    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);      
    p = new GeoPoint((int) (latPt * 1E6),(int) (lngPt * 1E6));

    mapController.animateTo(p);
    mapController.setZoom(16); 
    mapView.invalidate();
    mapView.setTraffic(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();

    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    package="com.app.ig.sap"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/> 

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/q_icon"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="false"> 

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Can anyone explain me why the map looks like this when it gets zoomed?

Comment: Can you post what your AndroidManifest.xml looks like?

Comment: Following is my manifest file...

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.app.ig.sap"
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"  android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"  android:anyDensity="true"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
 
 <application android:icon="@drawable/q_icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:debuggable="false">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

Comment: <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
   <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>   
  </application>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>

Comment: Are you seeing the tiles when you try to zoom in really close-in?  I think you're seeing the grayed-out tiles for areas that do not have satellite imagery available at that zoom level.  One other thought is that you're using a developer debug key.  Lastly, this might be a bandwidth/latency issue.  Are you seeing this when on a WiFi connection?

Comment: i think you are right. I dont get this issue when i am inside my building with wifi. Let me check it once....

Comment: What was the outcome of your testing with wifi and no wifi?

Comment: @andresf - hi i am sorry for the very late reply. What you said is right. IN wifi zoom in i am getting correctly whereas in my mobile network it creates some problems.

Comment: Post the same in answers part....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siva based on your reply to my comments this is ***not*** due to the imagery not being available on Google's servers, but rather to network latency.  There is likely a timeout for the image tiles to load--thus with latency you're seeing the gray tiles (as substitutes, which at least is better than a blank screen).  You could adapt your code to test the user's connection, and display a message to the user informing them that they have a slow connection and that the map may not render properly.

Comment: I think you'll need to post a new question for the android devs to answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that means that the zoom level you requested is not available on the Google Maps server, because you ask for satellite imagery which is not available at that zoom level.